# Lowering Ticks Per Second Without Mods

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-mods

I've been looking into Minecraft speedrunning categories and discovered TASing.

While looking into how they make these speedruns I learned that they use mods to make the tick speed slower to allow for more precise inputs. The only problem is that the mod that was recommended was for [1.12.1](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/tickratechanger). I was interested in more modern versions more specifically 1.16+.

The only possible solution I see is to use the randomTickSpeed command and set it to 0, but this does not derease the tick speed low enough.

**How would I decrease the tick speed without using mods for 1.16+?**

If there's no way to do so with commands **What mod could I use to lower tick speed for 1.16+?**

If there aren't any I'll just stick to 1.12 :)

Comment: Maybe if you use fabric with this mod : https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/fabric-tickratechanger-mod

It may work. Hope this helped, if not then sorry. :D

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is any way to decrease the tick rate without mods aside from using the randomTickSpeed command or by setting it in your world settings which means that there is no vanilla way of getting it slower than randomTickSpeed 0. If you are speedrunning on a server, you can try to overload the server which lowers the tps, though I don't think it can be applied to speedrunning. As for mods, I know that there was one a while back but have not heard of it anymore recently so I doubt it would be compatible with 1.16+. Finally, wouldn't lowering your tick speed be counterproductive while speedrunning ? It would probably also lower the spawning rates of blazes.

Comment: Lowering the tick speed would be bad for regular speedrunning but this is for a TAS, where they slow down the game to perform precise inputs that a normal human couldn't do.

Comment: when you lower the tickrate the final run is sped up to the real speed. so if its 5 tps it would be sped up 4x to become 20 tps